# Jooq for creating jasper reports queries

Tags: java, sql, jasper-reports, jooq

Can i use jooq to create queries for jasper report?

I mean query like this

```
select something from table where field=$P{someparameter}
```

the problem is the `$P{someparameter}` in the generated sql.

To be clear I just need the generated sql query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always resort to what jOOQ calls ["plain SQL"](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/), if there is some vendor-specific SQL expression that you would like to include. In your case, I'm guessing that the following might be sufficient for you:

```
Select<?> select =
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(TABLE.SOMETHING)
   .from(TABLE)
   .where(TABLE.FIELD.eq(DSL.field("$P{{someparameter}}", TABLE.FIELD.getDataType())));
```

Note that you'll have to "escape" the curly braces, as curly braces have a meaning in jOOQ's plain SQL template language.

You can then extract the SQL string like this:

```
String sql = select.getSQL();
```

And possibly extract the bind values as well:

```
List<Object> bindings = select.getBindValues();
```

Comment: in the result query string I get `$Psomeparameter` not `$P{someparameter}`

Comment: @res1: Sorry for the delay. I've updated the answer. You're right, of course.